# Editor Instance with a custom database query

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json

Question. I'm working on creating a data table that has a custom query instead of just a standard table. I would like to be able to use the existing $username and have records show based off that name. How would I change my code to be able to show records where the session $username = instructor1_full_id or is that possible within the editor?

```
    Editor::inst( $db, ‘dbo.data_record')
                ->fields(
                                Field::inst( 'instructor1_full_name' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
                                Field::inst( 'category' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
                                Field::inst( 'Metric_text' ),
 
                                Field::inst( 'response_value' )->validator( 'Validate::numeric'
, array("values"  => "0.0", "0.5", "1.0", "1.5", "2.0", "2.5", "3.0", "3.5", "4.0",
        "message" => "Please enter a range 0.0-4.0 with half increments" )),
 
                                Field::inst( 'fkey_course_id' ),
                                Field::inst( 'id' ),
                                Field::inst( 'first_name' ),
                                Field::inst( 'last_name' ),
                                Field::inst( 'fkey_semester_id' ),
                                Field::inst( 'course_code' ),
                                Field::inst( 'course_number' ),
                                Field::inst( 'course_section' )
 
                                )
                ->process( $_POST )
                ->json();
```